# Careers 2.0 - open to everybody now?

Tags: discussion, jobs

I opened a separate SO account just for work questions. 9 days later and with a rep of just **33** I got the Careers 2.0 invitation email:

> In recognition of your contributions to Stack Overflow, we’d like to
>   invite you to create a professional profile on Stack Overflow Careers
>   2.0.

It kind of shatters the illusion of achivement when I got my invitation on my main account.

Comment: 5 months after creating my [Sock Puppet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1833747/sock-puppet), I got the invitation as well (2 answers, 1 accepted, 110 rep). 9 days is pretty quick O_o

Comment: @RobW I had 2 answers 1 accepted too, I see a pattern emerging!

Comment: I'm crestfallen - I had to *request* an invitation on my SO account—and I had > 20K at the time :(

Answer (score 5):

Careers 2.0 is open to all developers who can prove that they are actually developers.  You don't even *have* to be an SO user.  The exclusivity of Careers 2.0 is not that it's only for the best developers in the world, it's for *real* developers.

Our goal when inviting SO users is to recognize a user who is likely a real developer;  someone who writes code professionally, or could if they found the right job. The other ways to [obtain a CV](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/get-one) include sharing your GitHub or CodePlex public repos, or just sending us a note and showing us you're a real person who programs for a living.

That said, 33 rep seems low.  We'll look into how someone as unqualified as your work alter ego snuck in =)

Comment: Here's another data point for refining your invite process. I got an invite after about 20 days with one asked question with a score of 0, one answer with a score of 1, and 16 rep.

Comment: @Immanuel: I beat you with a reputation of 15.

Comment: This is still happening and the email still comes across as scammy and fake. (I have 54 rep.)

If I was emailed because of my github activity, mention that! Saying it's because of my non-existent SO contributions makes this feel like a "You're the one millionth visitor" scam.